# Toggle visibility of menu based on screen width on page reload

Tags: javascript, html, css, toggle, onload-event

I have a `<ul>` menu with links and want to add some function which toggles the visibility of the menu depending on the screen width (i.e. it should hide the menu on screens smaller than 767px). I have tried this code, which seems to work when the window is resized. But on page reload, it does not:

```js
function toggleVisibility(i) {
  window.innerWidth < 767 && (i.style.display = "none")
}
```

```html
<ul onload="toggleVisibility(this)">
  <li><a href='link1.html'>Item 1</a></li>
  <li><a href='link2.html'>Item 2</a></li>
  <li><a href='link3.html'>Item 3</a></li>
  <li><a href='link4.html'>Item 4</a></li>
  <li><a href='link5.html'>Item 5</a></li>
</ul>
```

How can I make it hide the menu also on page reload?

Comment: you can do this with just css and media querys unless you're wanting to do it based on an elements width, but if its just window then use css

Comment: I have a `<button>` tag that also toggles visibility of the menu on mouse click, but did not add the code here as it is not directly related. The reason I wanted to use JavaScript is because if some users disabled JavaScript in their browser and would not be able to use that toggle `button`, then they would still see the menu. If I used CSS and set the menu as 'display:none' for small screens, then they would not be able to access the menu.

Comment: well then you need to handle that case but i'd suggest having and open class and a closed class and toggle that with a function.  otherwise you'd need to have resize event listening and recalculating styles on your menu which can get janky

Comment: explain your requirments more in your question and we can tehn advise you the best we can :)

Answer (score 0):

You would be much better off using CSS media queries for this.
An example:

```
/* any CSS declared inside will only apply when the window width is 766 or less */
@media (max-width: 766px)
{
    ul
    {
        display: none;
    }
}
```